# how to find basis for this space?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am supposed to find the complete and orthonormal basis for the space of trigonometric functions of the form :
$$\Phi(\theta)=\sum_{n=0}^N a_n \cos n\theta$$

It is given in the book that $$e^{in\theta}/ \sqrt {2\pi}$$ is a correct basis and then the conditions for orthonormality and completeness are proven true for it.

How to arrive at such a basis set?

I thought of using Gram-Schmidth process but didn't know how to apply for the given space.
Is using Gram-Schmidth process correct here and if so how to use it?

Is there any other method, particular for this or general to solve a problem of this kind?

Comment: You did not tell us on which interval you are observing the functions, so I will assume it is an interval of length $2\pi$, e.g. $[-\pi,\pi]$ or$[0,2\pi]$. Now, as it happens people have observed, long ago, that the functions $\cos n\theta$ and $\sin n\theta$ are all orthogonal to each other. This is a fundamental fact, easy to prove (via integration) and you are expected to know it. Surely, your subspace is spanned by only $\cos n\theta$ but they are *still* orthogonal, and all that is left is to scale them so that their norm is $1$.